# What do I need to change in my children components' props parameters after turning an object into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

I have one object in my App component, which child components take in as a parameter.

Now,i would like to expand this object into an array of objects. How should my props be passed into the child components?

i've tried un-deconstructing the props in the child component and console logging the errors, as I get errors of "undefined" and my map and reduce functions no longer work.

From this ->
Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Course from "./components/Course";

const App = () => {
  const course = {
    name: "Half Stack application development",
    parts: [
      {
        name: "Fundamentals of React",
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Using props to pass data",
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: "State of a component",
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: "Redux",
        exercises: 11,
        id: 4
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Course course={course} />
        {}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

To this Index.js

```
const App = () => {
  const courses = [
    {
      name: 'Half Stack application development',
      id: 1,
      parts: [
        {
          name: 'Fundamentals of React',
          exercises: 10,
          id: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Using props to pass data',
          exercises: 7,
          id: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'State of a component',
          exercises: 14,
          id: 3
        },
        {
          name: 'Redux',
          exercises: 11,
          id: 4
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      name: 'Node.js',
      id: 2,
      parts: [
        {
          name: 'Routing',
          exercises: 3,
          id: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Middlewares',
          exercises: 7,
          id: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      // ...
    </div>
```

Course.js

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";

const Course = ({ course }) => {
  let totalExercises = course.parts.reduce(
    (sum, part) => sum + part.exercises,
    0
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Header course={course} />
      {course.parts.map(part => (
        <p key={part.id}>
          {part.name} {part.exercises}
        </p>
      ))}
      {totalExercises}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Course;
```

How can i now pass this new array so that my child components can accept them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways this can be done.

1. You don't change child component. Do all code using array methods at higher level of tree which is consuming component.

like this index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Course from "./components/Course";

const App = () => {
  const courses = [{
    name: "Half Stack application development",
    parts: [
      {
        name: "Fundamentals of React",
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Using props to pass data",
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: "State of a component",
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: "Redux",
        exercises: 11,
        id: 4
      }
    ]
  },{
  }];

  return (
    <div>
      { 
        courses.map(course => (
          <ul>
            <Course course={course} />
          </ul>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

2. In the second method you need to change course.js

   It will accepts array of courses. Use map over there to iterate array of 
   objects.

Comment: thanks Jitesh! this is helpful!

as a general rule, is it better to execute the higher order functions such as map, filter and reduce in the same place where it is first consumed, in this case, Index.js?